# mySQL database structure

Tags: mysql

I've worked with mysql for some time but have never had to do anything anywhere near complicated. I'm working on a new project and need a little push in the right direction. Lets say I want to have a table that stores cats. Lets say I want to store the cats name, and food that the cat likes. Then lets say I want to query all cats that like fish, milk, and mice. I don't want to have the 'cats' table have rows for 'fish' 'milk' 'mice' that can be yes or no or 1 or 0. I think want I'm looking for is having a separate 'foods' table and then use the join statement. But I have no clue where to start looking or what to search for. Another way to think about this would be if you had a blog, and wanted posts to have categories. How would I store which posts are in which categories, and how would I query for posts by category?

I realize this is probably a very basic question, and would be happy with even a link to a tutorial explaining the structure / commands needed to pull this off! Thanks a lot!

Comment: What you have is a *many-to-many* relationship between `cat` and `food`, which is implemented by means of a *junction table*, such as the `cat_food` table in simshaun's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Table: cats
id
name

Table: foods
id
name

Table: cat_food
cid  (Cat ID)
fid  (Food ID)
```

**Query: Select cats that like fish**
SELECT
    name
FROM
    cats c
INNER JOIN 
    cat_food cf
        ON
    cf.fid = 2  -- Assuming food ID#2 is 'fish'
**Query: Select cats that like fish, milk, or mice**
SELECT
    c.name
FROM
    cats c
INNER JOIN
    cat_food cf
        ON
    cf.fid IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY
    c.name

**SCHEMA**
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cats` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `cats` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Sassy'),
(2, 'Tiger');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cat_food` (
  `cid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Cat ID',
  `fid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Food ID',
  UNIQUE KEY `cid_fid` (`cid`,`fid`),
  KEY `fid` (`fid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `cat_food` (`cid`, `fid`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 2),
(1, 3);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foods` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `foods` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Fish'),
(2, 'Milk'),
(3, 'Mice');

ALTER TABLE `cat_food`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `cat_food_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`fid`) REFERENCES `foods` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `cat_food_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cid`) REFERENCES `cats` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to make such an in depth answer!

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking right. You want two tables, a "Cats" table and a "Food" table. Your Food table would have some sort of primary key that your Cats table would reference as a foreign key. You could do a query perhaps like this:

```
SELECT * FROM cats WHERE food_id = 5
```

To understand how JOIN works in SQL, I would look through [here](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join.asp).

Comment: awesome! I after looking though the other answers and your link I can see where I can make a lot of improvements to my current databases!

Answer (score 0):

I can only offer the rails example.

In rails

I a perfect world where every post had 1 category

And you would see SQL like

```
Posts.find_all_by_category_id(Category.find_by_topic("sports").id)
# May generate 
SELECT ALL from `post`.* WHERE `category_id` = `7` 


class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many => :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belong_to => :categories
end
```

In the real world its a many to many relation

```
   class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_and_belongs_to_many => :posts
   end

   class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_and_belongs_to_many => :categories
   end
```

and rails would make the many to many join table for you behind your back

You would then go Category.find_by_topic("sports").posts to recover all the posts with a category of sports.

I don't know the detailed mySQL generated of the top of my head for how they do many to many relations.

Comment: Thanks for the rails example! I've been using PHP for a long time and really like it a lot because of my C background. The projects I'm starting to work on these days seem like good candidates for rails. My next endeavor will be learning rails for sure-- I've already started working with ruby and i love it so far!